# One noun to describe the competence of a person in generating wealth

Tags: single-word-requests

Please propose one noun to describe the competence of a person in generating wealth. The usage I have in mind is in the most fundamental, core, and conceptual sense of the word. For instance, evolutionarily women are attracted to men who have competence in generating wealth.

I would say my intended usage is typically generating money for themselves rather than others like attracting business to a company or creating opportunities for a community to prosper but these could still indirectly generate wealth for the person as well and if there is a term that also includes these, then the better.\

The skills involved in generating wealth might differ, for example, sales, craftsmanship, etc but I am looking for an umbrella term that encompasses the underlying concept.

Comment: Please be more specific.  What do you mean by "generating wealth"? Bringing in money for themselves?  Attracting business to a company? Creating opportunities for a community to prosper?

Comment: Please show how you intend this word to be used. Would [acumen](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/acumen) work?

Comment: @TimR thank you for your comment. I tried to add more details to the question so that it hopefully answers your concerns.

Comment: thank you @WeatherVane I tried to add more explanations to the question about the intended purpose. The definition of acumen is the ability to make good judgments and quick decisions, typically in a particular domain. Even though this skill can be useful in generating wealth, that's not its only intended domain and it is not the only skill that is needed for generating wealth. For example, communication skills can play a great role in generating wealth which is not covered under acumen.

Comment: If the definition of wealth isn't restricted, the term *competence* itself (from your question) may very well be the answer.

Comment: [Entrepreneurial](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/entrepreneurial) might work, but that's more about the activity itself rather than the quality required to succeed in it.  Perhaps fortunately, "entrepreneurialness" isn't attested, but we need a word which would have the same meaning.

Comment: thank you for your comment @jimm101 I considered that but the meaning of competence seems way too broader than wealth

Comment: You may consider the expression “*to have Midas touch*”

the ability to make money out of anything one undertakes.

Comment: Would you include criminal skills and personality traits like greed, miserliness, and sociopathy?

Comment: I would call this a talent, not a competence...

Comment: *"lucky"*? *"privileged"*? (1) Wealth doesn't correlate well with work, education, years, brilliance, or anything else often claimed as a cause. Wealth correlates with... **wealth** (inheritance). (2) Wealth is *produced by* labor, but it's accumulated by capital.

Comment: @Drew I think it could be competence. For instance, a high-end salesperson, fund manager, or software engineer can produce more wealth for themselves than an average employee even if they didn't have any capital to begin with

Comment: @Lambie it usually is both as the occupations I mentioned above can be developed by both talent and/or skill

Comment: @Alireza: It's not about what you or I might think. It's about what research has shown.

Answer (score 2):

**rainmaker**

> **What Is a Rainmaker**? A rainmaker is any person who brings clients,
> money, business, or even intangible prestige to an organization based
> solely on his or her associations and contacts. The rainmaker is
> usually regarded highly within the company by other employees and is a
> key figure like a principal, partner, or executive. The term is
> sometimes used in the context of political fundraising as well.
>
> KEY TAKEAWAYS A rainmaker is a person who brings clients, business,
> and money to their firm.
>
> A retired politician with a large following and the ability to raise
> campaign funds for others is also a rainmaker. The term is often used
> in the legal profession, but also business, investment banking, and
> entertainment. Technically, a rainmaker can exist in any part of any
> business. An individual that brings real, positive change to an
> organization is a rainmaker.

[Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/08/rainmaker.asp)

Comment: Obviously business-orientated, but OP doesn't quite disallow this. A useful term to know.

Comment: Thank you @Lambie this is a very useful term but I would prefer a more generic term than something used mostly inside business

Answer (score 0):

**money-minded** maybe
*(e.g money-minded person)*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).